# Twig template for specific node view

Tags: 9

I have a views-view--resources-filter.html.twig file.
Within here I have a better exposed filters form and I loop through the resources (node) with the available `{{ rows }}` variable. My question is, what is the naming convention to make a node view for an unformatted list where I use fields to show? So basically that it only styles the nodes within this view. I've been looking for a solution all day, but couldn't find anything really related to my issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be something like

`views-view-unformatted--my-view-name--my-display-name.html`

For more info, [turn on twig debugging](https://www.drupal.org/docs/theming-drupal/twig-in-drupal/debugging-twig-templates) and look in the Views module template folder at `/core/modules/views/templates/`.

Comment: Thanks! It works for me with this now: `views-view-unformatted--resources-filter.html`, I know that the name I used is the view name/machine name. But what is the best way to find the display name?

Comment: The display name of the view is shown in the Views UI for each display under the Advanced toggle. @JornReed