# Creating twig template for rows in a specific view

Tags: 9

Hi I have a view with the machine name news_filter. In the html every content type it's fields are inside a `.views-row` div. I want to create a template for those specific rows and maybe later also for each field too. But I can't find the right naming conventions to do so.

Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: For the Views style *Unformatted* see https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/310155/twig-template-for-specific-node-view. Turn on Twig Debug if you are unsure how your View is configured and which Twig templates are used.

Answer (score 0):

The template name would be `views-view-unformatted--news-filter.html.twig`, do clear the cache after adding the template file.

In views you cloud use a display with rendered entity display (Content) and a specific viewmode, use the template suggestion for the entity type, e.g. `node--news--VIEWMODE.html.twig`.

```
#views-view-unformatted--news-filter.html.twig
{% for row in rows %}
    {{- row.content -}}
{% endfor %}
```

```
#node--news--VIEWMODE.html.twig
<div class="news-item">
  <a href="{{ path('entity.node.canonical', {'node': 393}) }}?sort={{ node.id }}" class="use-ajax"
     data-dialog-type="full_screen">
    <article>
      {{ content.field_event_datum }}
      <h3>{{ label }}</h3>
    </article>
    <div class="click"><p>weiterlesen ></p></div>
  </a>
</div>
```